# hi guys im trying make screen recorder program with python but my program running 15 fps how i improve to 60 frame per second

Tags: python, opencv, video, pyautogui, screen-capture

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import pyautogui 
import time
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics


width = GetSystemMetrics(0) #it takes my default system resolution
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)

dim = (width,heigth)#tuple of my default system resolution


f = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID") # i dont know what this is

output = cv2.VideoWriter("test.mp4",f,60.0,dim)
#name of the video, some stuffs, fps of video, dimension of video



try:
    #this loop takes 15 screenshot per second and write it to output variable and its make 15fps 
    #video
    while True:
        
        image = pyautogui.screenshot() #takes screenshot
        frame_1 = np.array(image) #converting to arrays
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame_1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #changing the color (rgb)
        output. Write(frame)#writes array to output variable

        #this loop make it 15 times per second

        print(i+"\r")
        i = time.ctime() # i wrote it 'cause it shows how fast the loop is running per second


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

   

output. Release()
```

this code takes screenshots and write it to 'output' variable and playing it 60.0 fps
the problem is : my code takes 15 screenshot per second and play it 60 fps so when you watch the video you see everything fast
how can i solve it please help

Comment: repeat every frame 4 times.

Comment: You may just need to speed up your program so it can run 60 times a second, try making all the non-screenshot-taking functionality asynchronous so that doesn't slow down the loop. Then you'll also probably want to slow the loop down with some timekeeping. That or just change the framerate of the video to 15fps if you're okay with less smoothness in the video.

Comment: you "improve" this by _not_ reinventing things. there exist libraries for desktop capture and video compression already. find and use them. -- oh and XVID... your system will not have a hardware codec for that, so it'll waste CPU. -- @HenryWoody better to recommend profiling to know **where** time is actually spent. and why would you recommend _slowing down_ the processing?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz You're right that using an existing library for screen recording is the correct decision, but perhaps OP wants to do it this way. And I meant just to control the timing directly (in case its faster than 60fps after speeding up) so that the framerate is controlled by a timer instead of just by the processing time of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

pyautogui.screenshot() is takes too long time for capturing

This library takes 250ms in my M1 Mac

You should use another library for better perfomance

check like this

```
class Checktime():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        delta_second = 0.0
        self.s = datetime.now().second
        self.m = datetime.now().microsecond
    def delta(self, checkpoint):
        d = (datetime.now().second-self.s) + (datetime.now().microsecond-self.m)/1000000
        self.s = datetime.now().second
        self.m = datetime.now().microsecond
        print(checkpoint, d)

try:
    #this loop takes 15 screenshot per second and write it to output variable and its make 15fps 
    #video
    c = Checktime()
    while (True):
        
        c.delta(1)
        image = pyautogui.screenshot() #takes screenshot
        c.delta(2)
        frame_1 = np.array(image) #converting to arrays
        c.delta(3)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame_1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #changing the color (rgb)
        c.delta(4)
        output.write(frame)#writes array to output variable
        c.delta(5)

        #this loop make it 15 times per second
        
        i = time.ctime() # i wrote it 'cause it shows how fast the loop is running per second
        c.delta(6)
        print(i+"\r")
        c.delta(7)
```

result

```
1 5e-06
2 0.249821
3 0.00866
4 0.002012
5 3.6e-05
6 1.4e-05
Mon Aug 29 21:23:50 2022
7 7e-06
```

You can check screenshot() is defined in __init__.py of pyautogui

```
from pyscreeze import center, grab, pixel, pixelMatchesColor, screenshot
```

and in the *_init*_.py of pyscreeze you can check functions

I can not find any delay option of screenshot

you can try pyscreeze directly or use another library

```
def _screenshot_win32(imageFilename=None, region=None):
def _screenshot_osx(imageFilename=None, region=None):
def _screenshot_linux(imageFilename=None, region=None):
```